# create onChange in javascript issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign an change event to an element. I have

```
 var testDiv=getElementById('testDiv');

 var SelectMenu=document.createElement('select');
     SelectMenu.id='SelectMenu';
     SelectMenu.onchange=changeFuntion();

     testDiv.appendChild(SelectMenu);

function changeFuntion(){
 //it calls right after I load the page....
 alert('call');

}
```

html

```
  <div id='testDiv'></div>
```

I want the alert shown only when user change the dropdonw menu. However, it seems the alert is called right after the element is created.
Any tips? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the return value of the function `changeFunction` to `SelectMenu.onchange`, rather than the function itself.  Try...

```
SelectMenu.onchange = changeFuntion;
```

Instead.  The way you had it, i.e.:

```
SelectMenu.onchange = changeFuntion();
```

means:  call the function `changeFunction`, and assign the return value to the `SelectMenu.onchange` property.

Answer (score 2):

```
SelectMenu.onchange=changeFuntion();  <-- This calls the function
                                 ^^--- Remove the braces
```

supposed to be

```
SelectMenu.onchange=changeFuntion  ;  <-- This assigns the function pointer
```

Because of the braces the function is called immediately...